# Symfony 6: Validation field based on other field value

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I am trying to validate credit card number based on credit card type. Kind of like this:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
...
            ->add('card_type', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'AMEX' => CardScheme::AMEX,
                    'CHINA_UNIONPAY' => CardScheme::CHINA_UNIONPAY,
                    'DINERS' => CardScheme::DINERS,
                    'DISCOVER' => CardScheme::DISCOVER,
                    'INSTAPAYMENT' => CardScheme::INSTAPAYMENT,
                    'JCB' => CardScheme::JCB,
                    'LASER' => CardScheme::LASER,
                    'MAESTRO' => CardScheme::MAESTRO,
                    'MASTERCARD' => CardScheme::MASTERCARD,
                    'MIR' => CardScheme::MIR,
                    'UATP' => CardScheme::UATP,
                    'VISA' => CardScheme::VISA
                ],
                'placeholder' => 'Select card type'
            ])
            ->add('card_number', NumberType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new CardScheme([
                        'schemes' => [$builder->get('card_type')],
                        'message' => 'Your credit card number is invalid or not a ' . $builder->get('card_type') . ' type.',
                    ])
                ]
            ])
...
```

If above is not possible, how can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the $builder->get() method like that, as it does not return a string, but the FormBuilderInterface.

This solution worked out just fine:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
$cardTypes = [
    'AMEX' => CardScheme::AMEX,
    'CHINA_UNIONPAY' => CardScheme::CHINA_UNIONPAY,
    'DINERS' => CardScheme::DINERS,
    'DISCOVER' => CardScheme::DISCOVER,
    'INSTAPAYMENT' => CardScheme::INSTAPAYMENT,
    'JCB' => CardScheme::JCB,
    'LASER' => CardScheme::LASER,
    'MAESTRO' => CardScheme::MAESTRO,
    'MASTERCARD' => CardScheme::MASTERCARD,
    'MIR' => CardScheme::MIR,
    'UATP' => CardScheme::UATP,
    'VISA' => CardScheme::VISA
];

$builder
...
    ->add('cardType', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => $cardTypes,
            'placeholder' => 'Select card type',
            'mapped' => false,
        ])
    ->add('card_number', NumberType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new CardScheme([
                    'schemes' => array_values($cardTypes),
                    'message' => 'Your credit card number is invalid or not a allowed type.',
                ])
            ],
            'mapped' => false,
        ])
...
```

You can remove the

> 'mapped' => false

if the field is also declared in the Entity. With 'mapped' => false, you can add as many inputs to the form as you like, without adding them to the Entity.